# Verificar se todo $_POST foi enviado sem utilizar muitos ifs

Tags: php, post, if

Bom dia,

Tenho que verificar se todos os campos do form, enviado como $_POST, não foram em branco, isto até que resolvi. Mas eu queria ver uma maneira de não precisar usar muitos if/elif para checar cada index do $_POST iria:

```
if(empty($_POST['nome'])){?>
    <p>Campo NOME em branco</p>
<?php}
elif(empty($_POST['cpf'])){?>
    <p>Campo CPF em branco</p>
<?php}
elif(empty($_POST['endereco'])){?>
    <p>Campo ENDERECO em branco</p>
<?php}
...
else{

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
?>
```

Eu tentei apenas utilizar if(empty($_POST)) mas não funcionou, deixava passar mesmo com os campos em branco.

Answer (score 7):

Pode simplificar consideravelmente a lógica, se utilizar um array auxiliar para os campos em que está interessado. Nesse caso pode iterar os campos com um `foreach` e testar se cada um está definido em `$_POST`, e mostrar o respetivo texto de campo em branco quando não está.

Exemplo:

```
$valido = true;
$campos = Array("nome", "cpf", "endereco");

foreach ($campos as $campo){
    if (empty($_POST[$campo])){
        echo "<p>Campo $campo em branco</p>";
        $valido = false;
    }
}

if ($valido){
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
    $endereco = $_POST['endereco']; 
    //resto do código
}
```

Desta forma mesmo que tenha mais campos a verificar se estão preenchidos, apenas precisa de os acrescentar no array `$campos`.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer isso com um `foreach`, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    if (empty($value)){
        echo "<p>Campo ".$key." em branco</p>";
        exit;
    }
}

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
```

Se dentro da variável `$_POST` for encontrado algum campo vazio, exibe uma mensagem e finaliza o programa.

Answer (score 3):

Tenta alem de verificar se o valor é vazio, pois mesmo não preenchido ele vai retornar null e nulo já é considerado um valor, verifica também se existe, colocando o !isset.
Ficaria assim: `if ( !isset( $_POST ) || empty( $_POST ) )`

Answer (score 3):

A partir do php5.5 [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) passou a avaliar expressões e não somente variáveis. Uma forma de resolver o problema é conectar todos os campos através de conjunções (vulgo `E` lógico) e deixar que o if cuide do resultado da expressão.

**Importante:** caso algum dos valores contenha zero ele será avaliado como `false` o que vai gerar um falso positivo, que atento a esse detalhe.

```
$_POST = array('id' => '', 'nome' => 'fulano', 'email' => 'fulano@email.com');

if(!empty($_POST['id'] && $_POST['nome'] && $_POST['email'])){
    echo 'campos válidos';
}else{
    echo 'campos inválidos';
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/NHvih7)

Comment: Obrigado! Vai me ser bem útil!

Answer (score 2):

Eu trabalho da seguinte forma em meus projetos:

**1 -** Deixo o `input` de forma obrigatória, colocando o `required`:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" required>
```

Assim, o form não é enviado sem este campo preenchido.

**2 -** No meu arquivo PHP que recebe o valor, faço da seguinte maneira:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'] ? $_POST['nome'] : NULL;
```

Uso uma condicional ternária. Se meu arquivo PHP estiver recebendo o campo **nome**, atribui o valor para a variável, se não receber, atribui `NULL`.

Você também pode usar o `isset` do PHP. Que verifica se a variável foi iniciada:

```
$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : NULL;
```